# Django Simple Query Filter

Tags: django, django-filter

Trying to filter data by logged in user, but the code results in showing all users data instead of just the ones created by user. What am I missing here ?
There is no issue with serializer. I am guess I am missing some fundamental here.

views.py

```
   class TimelinePostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TimelinePostSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Timeline_Post.objects.all()
        user = self.request.user
        queryset.filter(author = user)
        return queryset
```

models.py

```
   class Timeline_Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

Actual results:

```
{
"count": 2,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "slug": "secon_post",
        "author": 8,
        "updated_on": "2019-08-06T18:47:43.915249Z",
        "text": "secon_post",
        "created_on": "2019-08-06T18:47:43.915249Z",
        "status": 0,
        "media": []
    },
    {
        "slug": "lkkej",
        "author": 5,
        "updated_on": "2019-08-06T18:04:11.175809Z",
        "text": "first Post",
        "created_on": "2019-08-06T18:04:11.175809Z",
        "status": 1,
        "media": []
    }
]
```

}

Expected Results:

```
{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "slug": "lkkej",
        "author": 5,
        "updated_on": "2019-08-06T18:04:11.175809Z",
        "text": "first Post",
        "created_on": "2019-08-06T18:04:11.175809Z",
        "status": 1,
        "media": []
    }
]
```

}

Comment: `queryset.filter(..)` does *not* alter the `queryset`, it simply constructs a *new* queryset that is a filtered copy of the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you forgot to assign the filtered queryset back to a variable. Also, you can filter by the user right away.

```py
class TimelinePostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TimelinePostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Timeline_Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```